# Changing Seaborn figure size

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Here is the code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,6)) # does not affect the following plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xticklabels(q9.columns.values[::-1], fontproperties=label_font, fontsize=14)
sns.barplot(q9.columns.values, q9.iloc[[1]].get_values()[0], palette="GnBu_d", ax=ax)
```

I had to set the font in this case, so I need the ax object. The final plot is really small, definitely not (15,6). I think by setting `ax=ax` changed the size of the plot to its default size.

Any idea on how to change the size of the figure in this case?

Comment: Remove the first line. In the second line, add the figsize argument `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,6))`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making two figures, with the call to `plt.figure` and `plt.subplots`. You are setting the size only on the first figure, but you are using the second figure to draw your barplot.

Comment: Since I am new to seaborn and matplotlib, could you show me the code to change the size of the plot. I think there are two solutions: 1. I shouldn't get the ax from the second figure,  but I don't know how to create one  2. how to change the size of the seaborn barplot.

Comment: `plt.subplots` has a `figsize` parameter, which you will see if you look at its docstring.